# Can we say $N$ is a linear combination of $\alpha'$ and $N'$ here?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$N=\alpha'\times N + s(N' \times N)$

So, N is a linear combination of  $\alpha'$ and $N'$ ? If so why?

Also we know $\alpha'$ and $N'$ is $perpendicular$ to $N$

I will complete a proof if that is true. Thanks

Comment: Please define the objects in your question. Are $N, N'$ and $\alpha'$ vectors (in $\mathbb{R}^3$)? Is $s$ a scalar? Does $\times$ denote the cross product?

Comment: Yes, all true. Also we know $\alpha'$ and $N'$ is $perpendicular$ to $N$ but I am not sure if I can use that yet.

Comment: $N$ is orthogonal both to $\alpha' \times N$ and $N' \times N$. Thus it is orthogonal to itself, so it must be the zero vector. The zero vector is a non-trivial linear combination of $\alpha'$ and $N'$ if and only if these vectors are linearly independent (i.e. they are not collinear).

Comment: Probably I am on the wrong route. N shouldn't be a zero vector I guess. You probably don't know differential geometry? I am trying to understand this solution of the question in the second page here http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~degt/math345/2000-f.pdf

Comment: If I can show that if will be enough... $y(t,s)=\alpha(t)+sN(t)$  and $N'(t)=\lambda(t) \alpha'(t)$   is given. I need to show $\langle \alpha',N(t) \times N'(t) \rangle =0$ all of them are vectors other than $\lambda$ and $s$

Answer (score 0):

Yes,we can If sN`+a=0 is true. N=axN+s(N`xN)
=axN+sN`xN =(a+sN`)xN
NxN=Nx(a+sN`)xN =(N.N)(a+sN`)-(N.(a+sN`))N   =(N.N)(a+sN`)                  (remember N.a=0 N.N`=0)  NxN=0 so  (N.N)(a+sN`)=0 if sN`+a=0 is true then N=0 is also true which means N=sN`+a and that shows N is linear combination of a and N`